# SSIS Issue: The Component cannot be added to the Data Flow task

Tags: ssis

I tried creating a new SSIS package and when I tried Doping a Data Flow Source (say OLEDB Source). I get the error The Component cannot be added to the Data Flow task. With the following Additional information 
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an incomplete installation of your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I noted that there are options "Other Sources" and "Other Destinations" .. i.e. maybe no requirement to even use the "Source Assistant" and "Destination Assistant" dialog options on the SSIS toolbox for the Data Flow.